# Why won't my $_GET Form insert the data (using PHP) into the MySql Database or Table?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, insert

Here is the html form:

```
<form action="register.php" METHOD=GET align="center">
<table border="2" align="center">
<tr>
<td>Desired Username:</td><td><input name="username" type="text" size"20"></input></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Your Email:</td><td><input name="email" type="text" size"30"></input></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Desired Password:</td><td><input name="password" type="password" size"20"></input>                                       </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Confirm Password:</td><td><input name="password2" type="password" size"20"></input>          </td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Register!" align="center"></input>
</FORM>
```

And here is the PHP code on register.php:

```
<?php
$myServer = "localhost";
$myUser = "Censored";
$myPass = "Censored";
$myDB = "Censored";

//connection to the database
$conn = "mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
or die('Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer')"; 

//select a database to work with
$selected = "mssql_select_db($myDB, $conn)
or die('Couldn't open database $myDB')"; 

//add new user to DB
if($_GET["username"] && $_GET["email"] && $_GET["password"] && $_GET["password2"] )
{
if($_GET["password"]==$_GET["password2"])
{
$sql="INSERT INTO Users(Username, Password, Email)              VALUES('$_GET[username]','$_GET[password]','$_GET[email]')";
$result="mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die (mysql_error())";
}

if ($result)
{
echo "<h1 align='center'>Registration Successful!</h1>";

echo "<p align='center'>Click<a href='index.php'> here</a> to log in.</p>";

}
else echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please <a       href='http://www.canilosa.zxq.net/index.php'>go back</a> and fix it.";
}
?>
```

I am a beginner in PHP and MySql. I have checked and rechecked all the usernames, passwords, databases, etc. The echo works and it says the registration is successful, but when I check my database there is no data.

---

Thanks SO much to everyone who answered!!! It works fine now :). As I said, I am new to all of this so most of the code was from snippets of tutorials and I just kind of skimmed it to see if it made sense. Thanks again! (I'm creating a game website with lots of PHP-MySql...so I'll probably be back here soon enough xD)

Comment: Use `$_GET['username']` instead of `$_GET[username]`.

Comment: Combine all the answers below. You will get a perfect solution.

Comment: Thanks SO much to everyone who answered!!! It works fine now :). As I said, I am new to all of this so most of the code was from snippets of tutorials and I just kind of skimmed it to see if it made sense. Thanks again! (I'm creating a game website with lots of PHP-MySql...so I'll probably be back here soon enough xD)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql functions that you are using are not correct ...

change

```
mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
```

to

```
mysql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
```

AND

```
mssql_select_db($myDB, $conn)
```

to

```
mysql_select_db($myDB, $conn)
```

DOCUMENTATION LINK http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysql.asp

Answer (score 2):

change this

```
<form action="register.php" METHOD=GET align="center">
```

to

```
<form action="register.php" METHOD="GET" align="center">
                                   ^   ^
```

also should be

```
$conn = mysql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass) or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer"); 

//select a database to work with
$selected = mysql_select_db($myDB, $conn) or die("Couldn't open database $myDB");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have used `mssql_connect` and `mssql_select_db` but the actual command is `mysql_connect` and `mysql_select_db`

Just replace your code with this

```
//connection to the database
$conn = mysql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
or die('Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer'); 

//select a database to work with
$selected = mysql_select_db($myDB, $conn)
or die('Couldn't open database $myDB');
```

Answer (score 0):

Corrections.

1. close method `attribute` in form `method="GET"`
2. insert statement as below

   `"INSERT INTO Users(Username, Password, Email)              VALUES('".$_GET['username']."','".$_GET['password']."','".$_GET['email']."')";`
3. `mssql_connect` should be `mysql_connect` and `mssql_select_db` should be `mysql_select_db`
4. `$result= mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die (mysql_error());`

**Difference.**

`$_GET['username']` this will look for username value passed in url as parameter.

`$_GET[username]` this will look for username constant which may not be defined in code.

Comment: `echo $_GET[username];` Will still fetch `$_GET['username'];` value, although with a notice that the index was assumed

Comment: @HankyPankyㇱ as per personal experience i faced it when i started learning php and it gave me undefined constant error...and learn time error never be forgotten.

Comment: Yes that is true it will give out a message. It is a `notice` and not an `error` and yes it should be avoided but that is not why their code is failing.